# How to update orders customer in real-time in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, e-commerce, analytics

Although I know surely have to look it up, I have to come here to offer some help or suggestion from someone here and so my problem is with the e-commerce website:

When a customer just completed the order or check-out successfully, staff immediately know what order just been created by somewhat customers through notification, I just intended for using Pusher or Laravel Echo for receiving real-times notifications but unfortunately, I realize that in my opinion, it's not suitable for the scenario which came from the orders update in staff's order management. It is just normal if an order has just been completed and updated to the table sporadically based on time, otherwise, if many orders are being completed and submitted constantly and so on in several seconds/minutes then the staff has needed to wait for update the UI orders list by javascript? I see they said using batch? but I don't know either that technique. So this be an absolutely wonderful thing if I receive your suggestion or if something can help me and I want to thank with grateful to you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Livewire and poll the orders table to get new orders on a controlled basis, or you can you the scheduling mechanism within Laravel to check for new orders. It appears they offer sub-minute task scheduling, but this probably isn't ideal really.

You can also use the dispatch and event system. There are several methods already built into Laravel

[Livewire](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart)
[Laravel Events](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events#dispatching-events)